# How do I use the use the for-looped print() outcome to fill in a new column in my data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, api

I created the following code to connect the df's phone_number column to an api (using "numverify") that verifies the validity of the phone numbers:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

main_api = 'http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=xxxx&'

number = file.phone_number
for n in number:

    phonenumber = urllib.parse.urlencode({'number': n})

    url = main_api + phonenumber + '&country_code=&format=1'

    numverify_data = requests.get(url).json()
    numverify_validity = numverify_data['valid']

    print(numverify_validity)
```

The outcome will be several true-false values coming out of the json for every phone number in the data frame .

I try to substitute the print with

```
file['numverify_validity'] = print(numverify_validity)
```

or

```
file['numverify_validity'] = numverify_validity
```

But the new column is not consistent with the print outcome.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

And also if you have other ways of verifying phone numbers that would be great :)

p.s. It is the first question I pose over here, so if you think I m using an inconvenient format please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a dataframe `file` you define a verificatoin function and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it to the `number` column:

```
def verify_number(n):
    phonenumber = urllib.parse.urlencode({'number': n})
    url = main_api + phonenumber + '&country_code=&format=1'
    numverify_data = requests.get(url).json()
    return numverify_data['valid']

file['numverify_validity'] = file.number.apply(verify_number)
```

---

Offline phone number verification is possible with [`phonenumbers`](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/) (a Python port of Google's libphonenumber library):

```
import pandas as pd
import phonenumbers as pn

file = pd.DataFrame({'number': ['+442083661177', '+12001230101']})
file['numverify_validity'] = file.number.apply(lambda x: pn.is_valid_number(pn.parse(x)))
```

Result:

```
          number  numverify_validity
0  +442083661177                True
1   +12001230101               False
```

---

**Update for input verification as requested in comment:**

```
import phonenumbers as pn

while True:
    try:
        number = input('Phone number: ')
        if not pn.is_valid_number(pn.parse(number)):
            raise pn.NumberParseException(None, 'invalid number')
        break
    except pn.NumberParseException:
        print('Please enter a valid phone number.')

print(number)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stef, this was really helpful, I will study more about lambda function :). Do you think I can apply somehow the (lambda x: pn.is_valid_number(pn.parse(x)) as a criteria for input data validation?